# NullPointerException when accessing a View when returning from Camera intent ONLY AFFECTING Samsung JB build JRO03L.L710VPBLJ7

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have an app where a user either selects an image or takes a new one, and then edits it.  Upon returning from either selection or capture, naturally, I have code to refresh the UI.  For the sake of simplicity, let's say the relevant code is:

```
LinearLayout options_holder;

@Override
public void onCreate {
    options_holder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.options_holder);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int res, int req, Intent data) {
    updateLayout();
}

public void updateLayout() {
    Log.d("LOG", options_holder.getClass().getName());
}
```

My android app works as expected on every other device I've tested except for Samsung Galaxy S3, Note, and Galaxy Camera.  With these specific Samsung devices, returning from image capture throws NPE on options_holder.  Returning from the chooser, however, behaves as expected, so I have NO clue what the problem is.

I suspect the build is the culprit.  Does anyone know how I might get around this?

Comment: Could you add stack trace?

Comment: A coworker suggested that I monitor the order in which lifecycle events are called (onCreate, onResume, etc.)  So, I've included that relevant info in my log, too: http://pastebin.com/FJPExaJD  (certain info, like my package name, has been redacted, and i cut out a lot of logs that were non-relevant to the thread, but the logs is still pure.)  Thanks!